# Override inherited method with different amount of parameters

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract

#### There are two tasks to solve:

First a class rectangle should  be inherited from the class GeoObjects.
Second a class square should be inherited from the class rectangle.

*The abstract class GeoObjects was given.*

```
abstract class GeoObjects{
    public abstract double Perimeter();
    public abstract double Surface();
    
    public static void main (String [] argv){
        double width = 4.0, height = 5.0, side= 3.0;
        GeoObject rectangle = new Rectangle (width, height);
        GeoObject square= new Square(side);
        
        System.out.println ("Perimeter = " + rectangle.Perimeter());
        System.out.println ("Surface= " + rectangle.Surface());
        System.out.println ("Perimeter= " + square.Perimeter());
        System.out.println ("Surface= " + square.Surface());
    }
}

class Rectangle extends GeoObjects{
    
    double width, height, side;
    
    Rectangle (double width, double height){
        this.width = width;
        this.height= height;
    }
    
    public double Perimeter (){
    return 2*(width+ height);
    }
    public double Surface(){
    return width* height;
    }
}

class Square extends Rectangle {

    double side;

    Square (double side){
        this.side= side;
    }
    public double Perimeter (){
        return 4*side;
    }
    public double Surface(){
        return side*side;
    }
}
```

I get the compiler information that the Square constructor has a different amount of variables than the one from Rectangle.

#### How can i solve this without hurting the requirement that Square has to be inherited from rectangle and not GeoObjects?

Comment: That's now what the error means.  You need to call the base constructor.

Comment: What is the **exact** error you get and which line causes it?

Comment: You can just use super(side,side) if I am reading this right in the Square class

Comment: Unrelated : Tell the person who gave you this code to better study Java naming conventions. Method names go camelCase always.

Comment: And just for the record: depending on you look at it, squares aren't necessarily rectangles in the OOP inheritance view, see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/238176/why-would-square-inheriting-from-rectangle-be-problematic-if-we-override-the-set for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler error message is informing you that you're attempting to call the superclass constructor in `Rectangle` with a different number of parameters than what the constructor has.  You are not explicitly calling a superclass constructor in `Square`, so the compiler has inserted a call to the default superclass constructor in `Rectangle` -- effectively `super();` as the first line in `Square()`.

But there is no constructor in `Rectangle` with no parameters; there is only one with 2 parameters.  Call it appropriately, by passing `side` to `super()` twice.

You'll also notice that the `Perimeter` and `Surface` methods no longer need to be overridden, because they will now use the proper values from the superclass.

Also, normal Java method naming conventions would have you name those methods starting with a lowercase character: `perimeter` and `surface`.

Comment: The proper Java method names would include a verb such as getPerimeter or computeSurface.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your Square class you will need to use `super(side, side)` to call the constructor from `Rectangle`.  You will no longer need the side class variable inside of Square, it can be simplified to just this:

Square:

```
class Square extends Rectangle {

Square (double side){
    super(side,side);
 }
}
```

Rectangle:

```
class Rectangle extends GeoObjects{

double width, height;

Rectangle (double width, double height){
    this.width = width;
    this.height= height;
}

public double Perimeter (){
return 2*(width+ height);
}
public double Surface(){
return width* height;
}
}
```

If you want to overload the methods in Rectangle or place methods that implement specific functions to square, you need to use the `width` and `height` variables instead of side.